# Macro as a case in switch-case not working in c

Tags: c, macros, switch-statement

I was making a college project. I faced a problem here is a over simplified version of this problem..

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define h1 2
#define h2 3
#define h3 4

const int ar[] = {h1,h2,h3};
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    switch (i) {
      case ar[i]:
        printf("yes!!!!!!!!");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It is showing error. I dont understand.Please explain...
Thank you.

Comment: ...and it works if you replace the macros manually?

Comment: `ar[i]` is not a macro.

Comment: This question violates language rules in a single place and a very obvious way, therefore voting to close as "simple typo"

Comment: ok so if i replace switch with a if statement will it work?

Comment: use if(.......)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`case` expressions needs to be *compile-time constants*. The expression `ar[i]` is not a compile-time constant, it's evaluated at run-time.

You could possibly solve it by some refactoring:

```
switch (ar[i])
{
case h1:
    printf("got h1\n");
    break;
}
```

Another way is of course to use `if` statements, as in

```
if (i == ar[i]) { ... }
```

Answer (score 4):

In C language, case labels must be compile time constants. in your code, ar[i] not compile time constant.

**C11 6.8.4.2 The switch statement(paragraph 3) :**

> The expression of each case label shall be an **integer constant**
>   expression and no two of the case constant expressions in the same
>   switch statement shall have the same value after conversion.